# Chrome dark mode detection not working in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This code works in MS Edge when the theme is set to dark but in chrome dark mode it doesn't, is this a chrome issue or should i be checking something else?

```js
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
  console.log('dark mode engaged');
  darkModeToggle();
} else if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches) {
  console.log('light mode initiated');
} else {
  console.log('default');
}
```

I'm expecting it to output 'dark mode engaged' in my chrome browser, it works in edge but not chrome.

Comment: Works in my Chrome developer console. Is Chrome set to force light mode? I know there's a Firefox setting that prevents dark mode detection called Resist Fingerprinting, perhaps Chrome has something similar.

Comment: @amphetamachine it's my windows settings, it's default theme for app's is light mode so i found the issue, thank You.